# How to identify the original cell location that contains the Max information that my formula gives me?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting, cell-format

What I am trying to accomplish is to Identify the Max of B1:B60, B60:B120, B120:B180 and so on throughout the entire column. I would also like to identify the location of those cells, and (ideally) make the cell visually easy to identify i.e. change the color of those cell or the text within those cells.

[image]

I already know how to identify the value of the highest numbers within the range `=MAX(INDIRECT("$B"&(61*ROW()-60)):INDIRECT("$B"&(61*ROW())))` but that does not tell me the location where that number came from. Without knowing the location of where the Max value came from is not very helpful in and of itself as I need to know the corresponding row and column information.

Any insights or help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to highlight the appropriate maximum values without using any helper columns. All you need is conditional formatting:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Create a new conditional formatting rule and set the formula to the following:

```dart
=B1=MAX(INDEX(B:B,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,60)*60+1):INDEX(B:B,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,60)*60+60))
```

Make sure that the `Applies to` range is set to `=$B:$E`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried to create a new rule in CF and I received this error
"you may not use reference operators (such as unions intersections and ranges) or array constants for Conditional Formatting criteria" any ideas on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: @AaronHooper Oh, damn! Different versions of Excel allow/disallow different things in conditional formatting formulas. Try creating a defined name, say `HighlightMax60`, with a `Refers to:` set to the same formula (`=B1=MAX(INDEX(B:B,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,60)*60+1):INDEX(B:B,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,60)*60+60))`). Make sure the active cell is `B1` when you do so. Then use `=HighlightMax60` for the the conditional formatting formula.

Answer (score 0):

Put your formula, `=MAX(INDIRECT("$B"&(61*ROW()-60)):INDIRECT("$B"&(61*ROW())))`, in cell F1, and copy down as far as you need so that it shows the max value for each batch of 60 rows.

To find out where the max values are, use this formula:

```
=MATCH(F1,INDIRECT("$B"&(61*ROW()-60)):INDIRECT("$B"&(61*ROW())),0) + (60*(ROW()-1))
```

Again, copy it down as far as you need.  That should give you the row number of each max value.  If you leave off the `+ (60*(ROW()-1))` term, it will give you the position of each max within the batch, rather than an absolute row number.

To highlight the max values, apply a conditional format with the following formula to column B:

```
=(B1=OFFSET($F$1, QUOTIENT(ROW()-1, 60),0))
```

This relies on having the maxima already calculated in column F.  If multiple cells in a batch have the maximum value, they will all be highlighted.

Alternatively, you could use a conditional formatting formula like `=(ROW()=OFFSET($G$1, QUOTIENT(ROW()-1, 60),0))`, where column G contained the calculated row numbers.  If there were multiple max values in a batch, this method would only highlight the first one.